# Error 8000: Bad sectors when installing Centos 6.5 Minimum

Tags: centos

I downloaded the ISO Centos 6.5 i386 and burned it onto a disk.  When I try to install it on my computer, I get the following with

```
install or upgrade an existing system

.loading vmlinuz..EDD: Error 8000 reading sector 16929
.EDD: Error 8000 reading sector 17176
.EDD: Error 8000 reading sector 17746
.
Loading initrd.img.......................
```

Then I allowed it to boot from the local drive.  The same thing happened again.  It doesn;t seem to be getting anywhere.

Comment: Redownload the ISO and burn it again.

Comment: @Braiam.  That fixed the problem.  Thanks very much,

Comment: Actually I did not need to redownload.  I just burned the ISO onto another disk.  Thanks again,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is provoked by errors in the disk. Should verify the downloaded ISO and burn the CD again, maybe reduce the speed. If disks doesn't work, maybe you should try USB instead.

Answer (score 0):

Insert the non-working DVD and run md5sum /dev/sr0. It'll report the md5sum and if it matches with the ISO md5sum, the DVD was burned correctly. If it does not match, there was some problem with the burn process. If you get any input/output errors while running md5sum, it's a proof that some parts of the DVD were unreadable.